# Call Activity - Expression - How to

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I have a question about how to solve this situation I have in my hands. The thing is, I´m trying to define a custom process in order to repeat an specific functionality but with a dynamic expression specified by the "father" process. Let's call the custom process as "B" and the process that calls the B activity as "A", then... In my A process I call the B process specifying a target expression "customExpression" that lately is used in a Service Task of the B process. The thing is that I don't know how to use this "customExpression" in the Service Task.

In the A process

```
<process id="A" name="A" isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
<callActivity id="callactivity1" name="Custom Service Task" calledElement="B">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:in sourceExpression="${customSpringService.execute(execution)}"></activiti:in>
  </extensionElements>
</callActivity>
<sequenceFlow id="flow10" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="callactivity1"></sequenceFlow>
<endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow11" sourceRef="callactivity1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
</process>
```

In the B process

```
<process id="B" name="B" isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
<serviceTask id="serviceTask1" name="Service Task 1" activiti:expression="${customExpression}"></serviceTask>
<endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="serviceTask1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow8" sourceRef="serviceTask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
</process>
```

I hope to explain myself well... 
Thanks a lot for your support.

There is question already posted in https://forums.activiti.org/content/call-activity-expression-how

Answer (score 1):

Finally I try the proposed solution by Mark (from activiti forum) and it´s working perfectly...

This is the code of the service

```
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.context.Context;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("customService")
public class CustomService {

    public void executeExpression(String expression, DelegateExecution execution) {
        Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getExpressionManager()
            .createExpression(expression).getValue(execution);
    }
}
```

And this is the one from the service task

```
<serviceTask id="customServiceTask_execution" name="Custom Service Task" activiti:expression="${customService.executeExpression("${accountService.getAccount(execution)}", execution)}"></serviceTask>
```

Instead of specifying "${accountService.getAccount(execution)}" directly as a method parameter I use a variable passed from the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

Look at docs: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask
Here you can find the exlplanation how to use expressions in ServiceTasks.

I think you miss the point of callactivty's usage. Please, have a look at specification:
http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCallActivity